# C# 画像URLダウンロードでエラー

Tags: c#

```
private async void download()
{
    string[] lines = textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    try
    {
        await DownloadImage(lines, @"C:\Users\Mia\Desktop\test\test\");
    }
    catch(Exception error){
        Console.WriteLine("e" + error.Message);
    }
}

static async Task DownloadImage(HttpClient httpClient, string uri, string path)
{
    using (var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
    using (var httpStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

static async Task DownloadImage(string[] uris, string path)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        await Task.WhenAll(uris.Select((uri, i) => DownloadImage(httpClient, uri, string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", path, i + 1))));
}
```

処理は成功しますが、エラーが表示されます。tryで囲まなければ中止してしまいます。

```
'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ja_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.resources.dll' が読み込まれました。モジュールがシンボルなしでビルドされました。
例外がスローされました: 'System.InvalidOperationException' (System.Net.Http.dll の中)
例外がスローされました: 'System.InvalidOperationException' (mscorlib.dll の中)
例外がスローされました: 'System.InvalidOperationException' (mscorlib.dll の中)
```

catche(Exception error)

```
An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

この`"\n"`は`Environment.NewLine`(=`"\r\n"`)が正しいのでは。

Comment: そこは[TextBox.Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx)で済むかも…

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージにはurlが不正とあります。C#にも画像にも無関係な問題ではありませんか？